# How to make another page the default page in asp.net boilerplate and Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-boilerplate

I've created a new project using the `asp.net boilerplate` a so it comes standard with the default landing page as the login page. So is it possible to create a new component and change the default landing page to the component that I have just created and create a link to the only page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the angular project under the **src/shared/auth** folder change the canActivate function to check if there is a session created and redirect to the specific component

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this._sessionService.user) {
       this._router.navigate(['FolderName/ComponentName']);
      return false;
     }
 }
```